# Ionic load URL within application NOT IN APP BROWSER

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am trying to load HTTPS url in ionic app.

I had tried to use iFrame but it shows error

**Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**

Used IN app Browser but its useless it shows extra UI that i dont want to.

Do you have any other idea to load HTTPS in ionic app.

Comment: you can hide Extra UI from inAppBrowser. with options

Comment: @NajamusSaqib what kind of option

Comment: @NajamusSaqib with option I m able to hide input URL. but i want to add within frame where i can more two button over it. is it possible to add within frame

Comment: No, Its not possible to add custom Buttons.